# apt-get install stack

Tags: apt, package-management

I would like to know that if you once type `sudo apt-get install` it checks whether the requested package is available.

- If the package is available it will automatically download him.
- If the package is not available it will tell you that the requested package doesnot exist

### Actual Question

If you misspell so for example instead of writing `sudo apt-get install program` (imagine that 'program' is package which exists) you will type `sudo apt-get install progran` **(hence the 'n' , consider 'progran' package to not exist)** then is the command added to some kind of stack container which regulary checks whether the package that didnot exist was created and if it was created then it will auto-download him ? So if package with name progran will be created for example 2 weeks after typing it , will it be automatically installed ?

- Does this function exists?
- If yes how do i stop it from happenning ?

**short form of the entire question :** simply the question is if i type sudo apt-get install package , while the package doesnot exist at the moment , will it be downloaded automaticly later if it will be created ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, no, it will not keep trying to download the package forever. That just doesn't make sense.

`apt-get` and `apt` are run on command. If a package doesn't exist, it'll tell you and make recommendations on some packages you may have meant to type. If a package doesn't exist, the script exits.

If the package does come into existence after you run the command, either because you added a PPA or it was added to the current repositories you have added, nothing will happen. `apt` won't download it, it won't install it. You have to try again yourself.

Comment: yes i guess you understood me , simply the question is if i type sudo apt-get install package , while the package doesnot exist at the moment , will it be downloaded automaticly later if it will be created ?

Comment: No, but if you are clever you can create a dummy transitional package, any updates (or existence) will result in a download during automated updates or any manual upgrades of all available packages. It must have the same name, mind.